# Adobe Acrobat - Dynamic Variables (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, acrobat

I'm currently creating a PDF file using Acrobat and I've added some JavaScript. A part of the code looks like this:

```
if (getField("q1").value == " " || getField("q1").value == ""){
 var se1 = "";
 var sum1 = "";
 var pu1 = 0;
}
else{
 var se1 = "\nS&E1: " + getField("s&e_1").value;
 var pu1 = 0;
 var s_e1 = getField("s&e_1").value;
 switch (s_e1){
    case "123": 
    pu1 = 123;
    break;
    case "456": 
    pu1 = 456;
    break;
    default: pu1= 0;
 }
}
```

My problem is that I have the same code 32 times and every time I have to add a new case, I have to add it 32 times. That's why I want to create dynamic variables so that I only have to add a new case once:

```
for(var i=1; i<=32;i++){
 if (getField("q[i]").value == " " || getField("q[i]").value == ""){
  var se[i] = "";
  var sum[i] = "";
  var pu[i] = 0;
 }
 else{
  var se[i] = "\nS&E[i]: " + getField("s&e_[i]").value;
  var pu[i] = 0;
  var s_e[i] = getField("s&e_[i]").value;
  switch (s_e[i]){
   case "123": 
   pu[i] = 123;
   break;
   case "456": 
   pu[i] = 456;
   break;
   default: pu[i]= 0;
   }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to replace [i] with the corresponding number (1-32)?

Comment: You mean in the strings? Like  `"q["+i+"]"`?

Comment: in the strings and in the variables. the string should look like this: `q1, S&E1` respectively `q2, S&E2` etc. and the variables like this `se1, sum1, pu1` respectively  `se2, sum2, pu2`
it is rather the variables that are causing problems

Comment: You don't want multiple variables actually. You want arrays. Remove the `var` (which are causing errors currently) and initialise `var se = [], sum = [], s_e = [];` before the loop. Your indexed access actually works otherwise.

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot!!